# Custom Repository in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, repository

I have a controller:

```
public function getAllItemsAction()
    {
        $content = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Item::class)->findAll();//<-(1)--THIS TO REPOSITORY
        if ($content === NULL) {

            return new View("Items not found", Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return new View($content,Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

How can I move this line (1) to the repository and then use this method from the repository in the controller?

Comment: Why do you want to move this in the repository ? Do you want to make a custom findAll method for you entity ?

Comment: @AntoineGalluet I want everything related to the doctrine to be in the repositories, and in the controller I would use methods from the repository

Comment: But even if you add a new findAll() function in your repository, you gonna have to call this function throught a `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Item::class)->youCustomFunction()`. So it won't change that much.

Answer (score 0):

The line you highlighted is actually not related from Doctrine: you are getting a service from the Dependency Injection container, and then calling a method on it.

What may bothers you is that you are using an alias (`getDoctrine()`) and the registry from Doctrine, which is there for conveniency.
But actually you could also declare you repository as a service and do this: `$this->get('item_repository`)->findAll()`.